# Why does laravel map function returns the whole object from relationship defined?

Tags: php, laravel

Say I have relationship of One `User` to Many `Post`

Where `Post` has a relationship of Many `Post` to One `Tag`

I am trying to get the title of `Post`, in the returned collection through API

Code below:

```
        $user = User::find($id);
        $data = $user->posts()->get()->map(function ($query) {
            $query['tag'] = $query->tag->title;

            return $query;
        })->values();
```

returns me just the object instead of the name:

```
[{
    // Post attribute
    "name": "Post Title 1",
    "tag":  {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Tag 1",
            "created_at": "2020-12-22T23:17:21.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-12-22T23:17:21.000000Z"
        },
}]
```

if I use different name in anonymous function, I will get the name and the object together:

```
        $user = User::find($id);
        $data = $user->posts()->get()->map(function ($query) {
            $query['tag_title'] = $query->tag->title;

            return $query;
        })->values();
```

Then I will get:

```
[{
    // Post attribute
    "name": "Post Title 1",
    "tag":  {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Tag 1",
            "created_at": "2020-12-22T23:17:21.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-12-22T23:17:21.000000Z"
        },
    "tag_title": "Tag 1"
}]
```

I have to change the code inside anonymous function to:
`$query->tag()->first()->title;`

For me to get what I want (just the name, not the object)

What is the explanation to this?

Comment: well you are loading the relationship so it will be in the serialized output, but also this code doesn't match any of this output or the relationship (assuming that is the serialized version of `$data` you are showing)

Comment: Yes `$data` is the returned response. Why are you saying it doesn't match any of the output? I tried it at postman and it returned exactly like that. (i'm using laravel 8)

Comment: You are right!! @lagbox, sorry I didn't realise making a stupid example. I was trying to convert my code from work to an example because i don't want to copy paste it here. I think now it should make more sense after I edit it

Comment: Anywho, `$query->post->title` is loading the relationship named `post` as it needs to load it to access it and that is the dynamic property ... `$query->post()->first()` is you directly querying the relationship and getting the result (no loading) ... which is why the relationship is showing up in the serialized output, because it is loaded   [`$query` is not an accurate name for this var at this point as it is a Model  `;)`]

Comment: But if I do the same with model in `php artisan tinker`, with `$post->tag->title`. Or if I would save it to a variable, it will give me the string. It only gave me trouble in the anonymous function in `map` function. Why is that happening?

Comment: this has nothing to do with map ... you have a Model instance, you load a relationship, you then serialize that model, the relationship will be part of that output ... even with your example you are just not serializing it    `(string) $post` you will see the serialized output including the relationship `tag`

Comment: I put a nice fat answer together for ya, hope it helps you out `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are accessing the dynamic property of a relationship Eloquent will try to load the relationship if it is not already loaded:

```
$post->tag->title
```

It needs to load `tag` to access it here. When relationships are loaded they will be included in the serialized output for the Model. You will see this `tag` relationship loaded in that output.

When you are calling `$post->tag()->first()` you are directly querying the relationship for these records. This does not "load" any relationship, it just lets you directly query it. Since you have not loaded the relationship here it will not be in the serialized output.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Relationship Methods Vs. Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

There are ways to 'hide' things in the serialized output, but it might not be a bad idea to think about something like a Transformer or a ApiResource (which Laravel provides) to serialize the data how you would like it to look.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Serialization - Hiding attributes from JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Api Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)

`map` is not doing anything special here. You have to remember that the object that is passed into your callback there is the same object you are returning. So you are only adding a field to the object and returning it (which in the process of doing that you are loading the relationship on the Model).

A suggestion to decrease the queries and hide the relationship:

```
class Post ...
{
    ...
    public function getTagTitleAttribute()
    {
        return $this->tag->title;
    }
}

$user = User::with('posts.tag')->findOrFail($id);

return $user->posts->append('tag_title')->makeHidden('tag');
```